# Azure calls working on local but not on production server - Firewall settings?

Tags: azure, firewall, windows-server-2016

We have an Azure set up where we use Azure as our proxy for sending data to our apps via Azure functions.

We are having issues because evidently our local development Windows environments send the calls to Azure, and we verify this by logging into our Azure portal, and watching any traffic to the calls in the Azure function console. When we run our code on our local machines, we see the traffic and the calls getting made, BUT when we try the same calls on our **production server environment (hosted onsite, Windows Server 2016) to Azure**, we can't see any traffic come through our Azure calls.

I am trying to chase down whether it is the Firewall on the production server machine and to see if there are any Outbound Firewall rules that need to be opened up or added to talk to Azure, but I have not seen anything by doing my Google searches that brings up local machine talking to Azure. Most of the articles that come up are about setting up a Firewall on Azure, not local firewall rules to Azure.

The application we are running is an onsite IIS hosted website with calls out to Azure.

Anyone have any pointers on where or what I should be looking at to see if there is any communication coming from our production server to Azure on the production server.  Which logs, rules, anything that could point us in a direction.  I felt I have looked in most places. I have looked in IIS logs, application logs (we just send a log saying that the call was sent)

But if there is a specific Firewall setting on the produciton server that I need to add, I don't know what that would be and if anyone does know, it would be very helpful.

UPDATE:

We have so far found that we can hit the functions through a browser enabling GET requests and other functions that allow GET requests.  The issue seems to be either IIS or a permission with IIS or the application itself. We actually set the permissions on our application on our server to "Everyone" just to see what would happen, on the folder for the application and still have not have any luck.  The calls we are calling are actually POST to the Azure function.  We don't have Postman on the machine.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you are trying to call in Azure, it sounds like it's an Azure Function you are trying to hit, is that the case? Can you confirm if you have any IP restrictions setup on the function app it's self?

Comment: @SamCogan, I can check.  But I am not sure this is the case. We never really set that up.  However we can try. I am adding an update of what I we have found as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're calling out to an Azure Funciton, which is not running on an App Service Environment, or behind API management or similar, then the only place you can restrict access is on the networking tab of the settings of the function. If you don't have this configured then the function is not where the issue is.

If traffic outbound from your on-prem server is being blocked, then you will need to talk to your IT team to get that opened up. You don't mention how you're calling your funciton, but if it is an HTTP trigger, then you would need port 443 outbound open.